# How to draw a rectangle outline in SDL 2.0

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to draw a rectangle outline in SDL 2.0 in order to use as a selection box. Does anyone know how to make one in SDL 2.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for the [SDL_RenderDrawRect](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawRect):

```
int SDL_RenderDrawRect(SDL_Renderer*   renderer,
                   const SDL_Rect* rect);
```

Typical usage would be:

```
SDL_Rect rectToDraw = {100,100,100,100} // Just some random rect

//Set Color of Rect with SDL_SetRenderDrawColor if needed

SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &rectToDraw);
```

To draw a filled rect it would then be with [SDL_RenderFillRect](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderFillRect)

Comment: Thanks. I actually found this last night. Just shows that I wasn't looking hard enough.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on sdl 1.2?